# java.lang.Exception: Failed resolving method startActivityForResult on class android.app.Activity

Tags: android, nativescript

A Nativescript (4.1) angular project (tns create app --ng) starts activity. But I get an error.

```
JS: ERROR Error: java.lang.Exception: Failed resolving method startActivityForResult on class android.app.Activity
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.resolveMethodOverload(Runtime.java:1062)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1101)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:983)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:970)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:954)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:946)

ngAfterViewInit() {
    const intent = new android.content.Intent((android.provider.Settings as any).ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
    android.net.Uri.parse('package:' + application.android.context.getPackageName()));
    const activity = application.android.foregroundActivity || application.android.startActivity;
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this error.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
        const application = require("application");
        const RESULT_CODE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION = 1234;
        const intent = new android.content.Intent((android.provider.Settings as any).ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
        android.net.Uri.parse('package:' + application.android.context.getPackageName()));
        const activity = application.android.foregroundActivity || application.android.startActivity;
        application.android.on(application.AndroidApplication.activityResultEvent, (args) => console.log(args));
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_CODE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
    }
```